# How To Get Chat Id of Users on telegram by there Mobile Number in PHP?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have gone through many forums and API of telegram also.
But could not get the proper answer.

Well here is my main question.
I have list of users with their mobile numbers in my database and from all those, I want to send them messages on their telegram. So for that I will need their chat ID. How can I retrieve that by their MobileNumber? If I will have chat id, I am able to send message to them by using the following reference.

[Telegram php example send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620409/telegram-php-example-send-message)

I have visited the following link to get the chat id by manually from BOT by user itself. But I want automatic from script.

[How to obtain Telegram chat_id for a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078710/how-to-obtain-telegram-chat-id-for-a-specific-user)

Thanks.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: thanks for your response. I will go through of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PHP. but there is a way to do this:

As you know you can send a contact in telegram bot using its phoneNumber and a firsName (Doesn't need to be the real first name of the contact who owns that number).

After sending the contact to a chatID(no matter what chatID you choose, can be your own personal chat ID), you can look for its UserID.

> Now if the person exists in Telegram you will get a long number that
>   stands for his/her UserID or chatID but if not the long will be **0**.

In C# I used this piece of code to see whether a phone number exists in telegram or not and it worked very well.

```
string s = "+44....";    //the phone number
var req2 = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new SendContact(update.Message.Chat.Id, s, "Name"));
if(req2.Contact.UserId == 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("The contact does not exist in Telegram");
}else
{
  Console.WriteLine("The contact exists in telegram with UserID:{0}",req2.Contact.UserId.ToString());
}
```

I believe this can be done in PHP too.

Comment: After doing so much research - I almost tried something similar to your answer. Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: There is a limitation on the number of user_ids you can get with this method. You can only use "sendContact" 20 times in a day. After that any attempt to use sendContact to any chat_id, will result in "Error:429 Too Many Requests: retry after XXXX". But all other functionalities of the bot remain intact. This is not well documented.

Comment: @MehrdadNazmdar I haven't tested that, but for this question it works because he just wanted to know the chat id of a mobile number.

Answer (score 2):

By Telegram bot you can send messages only to users that started chat with your bot. you can obtain their chat_id (not phone number) from received query.

So you can not send message to another people even if you have their phone numbers.

Comment: I agree with you. I found the same information ! 
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use bots to find a user on Telegram using their phone number.

Comment: Hey Ariaby, THanks for your comment. so Is there any other way to retrieve Chat Id by using phonenumber in TELEGRAM API?

Comment: No and even if you have a chat_id you can't send them message because the user has to initiate the conversation with bot.

Comment: Exactly ! There is no way ! Thanks for your answer btw!